# Why am I unable to access req.user.username while using passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, passport.js

I'm using passport.js for authentication, and forgive me if my phrasing is incorrect as I'm still new to this. After logging in via google, I redirect to the profile page. However, when I send the request Object (User), only the first parameter of the object is available to me through req.user (the id). I'll show the passport-setup, along with the routes and hopefully that should be enough information.

passport setup:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const User = require('../models/User')
 
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id) 
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user.id) 
    })
})

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
    // options for the google strat
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
    clientID: process.env.clientID,
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    // passport callback function

    User.findOne({googleId:profile.id}).then((currentUser) => {
        if(currentUser){
        // already have a user
        console.log('user is: ' + currentUser)
        done(null, currentUser)
        } else {
            // if not, create user in db
            new User({
            username: profile.displayName,
            googleId: profile.id
        }).save().then((newUser) => {
            console.log('new user created' + newUser)
            done(null, newUser)
        })
    }
        
})

}))
```

auth route:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport')

// auth login
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
})

// auth logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    // handle the passport
    res.send('logging out')
})

// auth with google
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));

// callback route for google to redirect to
router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    // res.send(req.user)
    res.redirect('/profile')
})

module.exports = router
```

If I type res.user.username within the last route, I get my username. But when I send the request to the redirect, req.user.username returns undefined, while req.user gives me the first parameter, which is the id. Looks something like this.

```
welcome 63638beb83e373e1acc7914c
```

Lastly, here is my profile route:

```
const router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // req.user.username returns undefined
    res.send('this is your profile, welcome ' + req.user)
})

module.exports = router
```

And Schema incase it's needed:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    googleId: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema)

module.exports= User;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return entire user object here

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user) 
    })
})
```